# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' on require("file_path") statement

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my node.js application I am returning some HTML from a request. I am using express so I use a require() statement to get it in a variable and return it with the request. This was all working fine until suddenly it stopped working without me knowingly changing anything.

**Error**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (path/controllers/homepage.js)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (path/routes/home.js)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
```

I have isolated the culprit code to the first line of the following:

```
const page = require("../Front End/Index.html");

exports.getHome = (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(page);
}
```

Other questions on stack overflow point to the HTML file being problematic, so below is the  segment (also where the error is pointed to)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Index.css">
    <title>Wildfire</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="Assets/wildfirelogo64.png">
</head>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require()` can be used to load and run Javascript files or to read and parse JSON files.  It is not for loading regular text files.  You are getting the error about the `<` symbol because it's trying to parse your HTML as Javascript and obviously that just gives a Javascript syntax error.

If you want to preload a piece of HTML, you can use `fs.readFileSync()`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const page = fs.readFileSync('../Front End/Index.html');

exports.getHome = (req, res) => {
    res.send(page);
}
```

Or, you can just let Express handle reading the file for you:

```
exports.getHome = (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("../Front End/Index.html", { root: __dirname });
}
```

Comment: When I do the first option, I get the error "TypeError: path must be a string to res.sendFile", and when I do the second option I get the error "TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile". Is there a way that I can send a file without the absolute path, or using the first option?

Comment: @skelegorg - My first option doesn't contain `res.sendFile()`.  If you mean the second option in my answer, then see the revision to my answer and adjust the `root` option as needed for your directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can not `require` an html file, HTML syntax cannot execute as a JS syntax.

If you want to send an HTML file to the client with express application, just follow some simple example on the internet:

```
exports.getHome = (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("../Front End/Index.html"); // send it
}
```